# When I run my code I am getting an error. It is saying that 'SFA ' is not defined but I set SFA to a user input

Tags: python, replace

My problem is that whenever I run this code I get an error which says that
"if SFA == "yes": NameError: name 'SFA' is not defined"
I am not really sure what I am doing wrong, because I thought that by setting SFA=input("text here:"), I would define SFA so that when it goes to the next line (if SFA == "yes":), if the users input was "yes" the code could proceed.

```
def first():
    SFA=input("Would you like the information to be stored using encryption?(Answer in 'yes' or 'no'):")

if SFA == "yes":
    RM=IA
#creating a simple encryption method
    RM=RM.replace("b","0").replace("a",chr(ord("a")+1)).replace("b","1").replace("0","b")
    RM=RM.replace("c","2").replace("b",chr(ord("b")+1)).replace("1","b").replace("c","3")
    RM=RM.replace("2","c").replace("d","4").replace("c",chr(ord("c")+1)).replace("3","c")
    RM=RM.replace("d","5").replace("4","d").replace("e","6").replace("d",chr(ord("d")+1)).replace("5","d")
    RM=RM.replace("e","7").replace("6","e").replace("f","8").replace("e",chr(ord("e")+1)).replace("7","e")
    RM=RM.replace("f","9").replace("8","f").replace("g","€").replace("f",chr(ord("f")+1)).replace("9","f")
    RM=RM.replace("g","▲").replace("€","g").replace("h","¶").replace("g",chr(ord("g")+1)).replace("▲","g")
    RM=RM.replace("h","ß").replace("¶","h").replace("i","%").replace("h",chr(ord("h")+1)).replace("ß","h")
    RM=RM.replace("i","¤").replace("%","i").replace("j","&").replace("i",chr(ord("i")+1)).replace("¤","i")
    RM=RM.replace("j","¥").replace("&","j").replace("k","‰").replace("j",chr(ord("j")+1)).replace("¥","j")
    RM=RM.replace("k","Ë").replace("‰","k").replace("l","_").replace("k",chr(ord("k")+1)).replace("Ë","k")
    RM=RM.replace("l","Ð").replace("_","l").replace("m","Š").replace("l",chr(ord("l")+1)).replace("Ð","l")
    RM=RM.replace("m","▼").replace("Š","m").replace("n","[").replace("m",chr(ord("m")+1)).replace("▼","m")
    RM=RM.replace("n","]").replace("[","n").replace("o","{").replace("n",chr(ord("n")+1)).replace("]","n")
    RM=RM.replace("o","}").replace("{","o").replace("p","|").replace("o",chr(ord("o")+1)).replace("}","o")
    RM=RM.replace("p",":").replace("|","p").replace("q",";").replace("p",chr(ord("p")+1)).replace(":","p")
    RM=RM.replace("q","Ó").replace(";","q").replace("r","§").replace("q",chr(ord("q")+1)).replace("Ó","q")
    RM=RM.replace("r","/").replace("§","r").replace("s",">").replace("r",chr(ord("r")+1)).replace("/","r")
    RM=RM.replace("s","Õ").replace(">","s").replace("t","<").replace("s",chr(ord("s")+1)).replace("Õ","s")
    RM=RM.replace("t","Ô").replace("<","t").replace("u","~").replace("t",chr(ord("t")+1)).replace("Ô","t")
    RM=RM.replace("u","ü").replace("~","u").replace("v","é").replace("u",chr(ord("u")+1)).replace("ü","u")
    RM=RM.replace("v","â").replace("é","v").replace("w","ä").replace("v",chr(ord("v")+1)).replace("â","v")
    RM=RM.replace("w","ç").replace("ä","w").replace("x","ê").replace("w",chr(ord("w")+1)).replace("ç","w")
    RM=RM.replace("x","┐").replace("ê","x").replace("y","└").replace("x",chr(ord("x")+1)).replace("┐","x")
    RM=RM.replace("y","─").replace("└","y").replace("z","┼").replace("y",chr(ord("y")+1)).replace("─","y")
    RM=RM.replace("z","╛").replace("┼","z").replace("a","…").replace("z",chr(ord("z")-25)).replace("╛","z")
    RM=RM.replace("B","0").replace("A",chr(ord("A")+1)).replace("B","1").replace("0","B")
    RM=RM.replace("C","2").replace("B",chr(ord("B")+1)).replace("1","B").replace("C","3")
    RM=RM.replace("2","C").replace("D","4").replace("C",chr(ord("C")+1)).replace("3","C")
    RM=RM.replace("D","5").replace("4","D").replace("E","6").replace("D",chr(ord("D")+1)).replace("5","D")
    RM=RM.replace("E","7").replace("6","E").replace("F","8").replace("E",chr(ord("E")+1)).replace("7","E")
    RM=RM.replace("F","9").replace("8","F").replace("G","€").replace("F",chr(ord("F")+1)).replace("9","F")
    RM=RM.replace("G","▲").replace("€","G").replace("H","¶").replace("G",chr(ord("G")+1)).replace("▲","G")
    RM=RM.replace("H","ß").replace("¶","H").replace("I","%").replace("H",chr(ord("H")+1)).replace("ß","H")
    RM=RM.replace("I","¤").replace("%","I").replace("J","&").replace("I",chr(ord("I")+1)).replace("¤","I")
    RM=RM.replace("J","¥").replace("&","J").replace("K","‰").replace("J",chr(ord("J")+1)).replace("¥","J")
    RM=RM.replace("K","Ë").replace("‰","K").replace("L","_").replace("K",chr(ord("K")+1)).replace("Ë","K")
    RM=RM.replace("L","Ð").replace("_","L").replace("M","Š").replace("L",chr(ord("L")+1)).replace("Ð","L")
    RM=RM.replace("M","▼").replace("Š","M").replace("N","[").replace("M",chr(ord("M")+1)).replace("▼","M")
    RM=RM.replace("N","]").replace("[","N").replace("O","{").replace("N",chr(ord("N")+1)).replace("]","N")
    RM=RM.replace("O","}").replace("{","O").replace("P","|").replace("O",chr(ord("O")+1)).replace("}","O")
    RM=RM.replace("P",":").replace("|","P").replace("Q",";").replace("P",chr(ord("P")+1)).replace(":","P")
    RM=RM.replace("Q","Ó").replace(";","Q").replace("R","§").replace("Q",chr(ord("Q")+1)).replace("Ó","Q")
    RM=RM.replace("R","/").replace("§","R").replace("S","Σ").replace("R",chr(ord("R")+1)).replace("/","R")
    RM=RM.replace("S","Õ").replace("Σ","S").replace("T","σ").replace("S",chr(ord("S")+1)).replace("Õ","S")
    RM=RM.replace("T","Ô").replace("σ","T").replace("U","~").replace("T",chr(ord("T")+1)).replace("Ô","T")
    RM=RM.replace("U","ü").replace("~","U").replace("V","é").replace("U",chr(ord("U")+1)).replace("ü","U")
    RM=RM.replace("V","â").replace("é","V").replace("W","ä").replace("V",chr(ord("V")+1)).replace("â","V")
    RM=RM.replace("W","ç").replace("ä","W").replace("X","ê").replace("W",chr(ord("W")+1)).replace("ç","W")
    RM=RM.replace("X","┐").replace("ê","X").replace("Y","└").replace("X",chr(ord("X")+1)).replace("┐","X")
    RM=RM.replace("Y","─").replace("└","Y").replace("Z","┼").replace("Y",chr(ord("Y")+1)).replace("─","Y")
    RM=RM.replace("Z","╛").replace("┼","Z").replace("A","…").replace("Z",chr(ord("Z")-25)).replace("╛","Z")
elif SFA == "no":
    print("no way")
else:
    print("what?")
    first()
first()
```

Comment: `SFA` exists only in the `first` function.

Comment: The majority of your example is not relevant to your problem/question. Please try to reduce your examples to a [mre] prior to posting. Often just doing that will highlight the problem for you and you may not have to post. - Sometimes it is hard to see the tree for the forest.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces), [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html)

Comment: the SFA is only defined inside `first()`

Answer (score 1):

`SFA` only is local inside in the `first()` function, so you should make a global var and call it first:

```
def first():
    global SFA
    SFA=input("Would you like the information to be stored using encryption?(Answer in 'yes' or 'no'):")

first()
if SFA == "yes":
    RM=IA
#creating a simple encryption method
    RM=RM.replace("b","0").replace("a",chr(ord("a")+1)).replace("b","1").replace("0","b")
    RM=RM.replace("c","2").replace("b",chr(ord("b")+1)).replace("1","b").replace("c","3")
    RM=RM.replace("2","c").replace("d","4").replace("c",chr(ord("c")+1)).replace("3","c")
    RM=RM.replace("d","5").replace("4","d").replace("e","6").replace("d",chr(ord("d")+1)).replace("5","d")
    RM=RM.replace("e","7").replace("6","e").replace("f","8").replace("e",chr(ord("e")+1)).replace("7","e")
    RM=RM.replace("f","9").replace("8","f").replace("g","€").replace("f",chr(ord("f")+1)).replace("9","f")
    RM=RM.replace("g","▲").replace("€","g").replace("h","¶").replace("g",chr(ord("g")+1)).replace("▲","g")
    RM=RM.replace("h","ß").replace("¶","h").replace("i","%").replace("h",chr(ord("h")+1)).replace("ß","h")
    RM=RM.replace("i","¤").replace("%","i").replace("j","&").replace("i",chr(ord("i")+1)).replace("¤","i")
    RM=RM.replace("j","¥").replace("&","j").replace("k","‰").replace("j",chr(ord("j")+1)).replace("¥","j")
    RM=RM.replace("k","Ë").replace("‰","k").replace("l","_").replace("k",chr(ord("k")+1)).replace("Ë","k")
    RM=RM.replace("l","Ð").replace("_","l").replace("m","Š").replace("l",chr(ord("l")+1)).replace("Ð","l")
    RM=RM.replace("m","▼").replace("Š","m").replace("n","[").replace("m",chr(ord("m")+1)).replace("▼","m")
    RM=RM.replace("n","]").replace("[","n").replace("o","{").replace("n",chr(ord("n")+1)).replace("]","n")
    RM=RM.replace("o","}").replace("{","o").replace("p","|").replace("o",chr(ord("o")+1)).replace("}","o")
    RM=RM.replace("p",":").replace("|","p").replace("q",";").replace("p",chr(ord("p")+1)).replace(":","p")
    RM=RM.replace("q","Ó").replace(";","q").replace("r","§").replace("q",chr(ord("q")+1)).replace("Ó","q")
    RM=RM.replace("r","/").replace("§","r").replace("s",">").replace("r",chr(ord("r")+1)).replace("/","r")
    RM=RM.replace("s","Õ").replace(">","s").replace("t","<").replace("s",chr(ord("s")+1)).replace("Õ","s")
    RM=RM.replace("t","Ô").replace("<","t").replace("u","~").replace("t",chr(ord("t")+1)).replace("Ô","t")
    RM=RM.replace("u","ü").replace("~","u").replace("v","é").replace("u",chr(ord("u")+1)).replace("ü","u")
    RM=RM.replace("v","â").replace("é","v").replace("w","ä").replace("v",chr(ord("v")+1)).replace("â","v")
    RM=RM.replace("w","ç").replace("ä","w").replace("x","ê").replace("w",chr(ord("w")+1)).replace("ç","w")
    RM=RM.replace("x","┐").replace("ê","x").replace("y","└").replace("x",chr(ord("x")+1)).replace("┐","x")
    RM=RM.replace("y","─").replace("└","y").replace("z","┼").replace("y",chr(ord("y")+1)).replace("─","y")
    RM=RM.replace("z","╛").replace("┼","z").replace("a","…").replace("z",chr(ord("z")-25)).replace("╛","z")
    RM=RM.replace("B","0").replace("A",chr(ord("A")+1)).replace("B","1").replace("0","B")
    RM=RM.replace("C","2").replace("B",chr(ord("B")+1)).replace("1","B").replace("C","3")
    RM=RM.replace("2","C").replace("D","4").replace("C",chr(ord("C")+1)).replace("3","C")
    RM=RM.replace("D","5").replace("4","D").replace("E","6").replace("D",chr(ord("D")+1)).replace("5","D")
    RM=RM.replace("E","7").replace("6","E").replace("F","8").replace("E",chr(ord("E")+1)).replace("7","E")
    RM=RM.replace("F","9").replace("8","F").replace("G","€").replace("F",chr(ord("F")+1)).replace("9","F")
    RM=RM.replace("G","▲").replace("€","G").replace("H","¶").replace("G",chr(ord("G")+1)).replace("▲","G")
    RM=RM.replace("H","ß").replace("¶","H").replace("I","%").replace("H",chr(ord("H")+1)).replace("ß","H")
    RM=RM.replace("I","¤").replace("%","I").replace("J","&").replace("I",chr(ord("I")+1)).replace("¤","I")
    RM=RM.replace("J","¥").replace("&","J").replace("K","‰").replace("J",chr(ord("J")+1)).replace("¥","J")
    RM=RM.replace("K","Ë").replace("‰","K").replace("L","_").replace("K",chr(ord("K")+1)).replace("Ë","K")
    RM=RM.replace("L","Ð").replace("_","L").replace("M","Š").replace("L",chr(ord("L")+1)).replace("Ð","L")
    RM=RM.replace("M","▼").replace("Š","M").replace("N","[").replace("M",chr(ord("M")+1)).replace("▼","M")
    RM=RM.replace("N","]").replace("[","N").replace("O","{").replace("N",chr(ord("N")+1)).replace("]","N")
    RM=RM.replace("O","}").replace("{","O").replace("P","|").replace("O",chr(ord("O")+1)).replace("}","O")
    RM=RM.replace("P",":").replace("|","P").replace("Q",";").replace("P",chr(ord("P")+1)).replace(":","P")
    RM=RM.replace("Q","Ó").replace(";","Q").replace("R","§").replace("Q",chr(ord("Q")+1)).replace("Ó","Q")
    RM=RM.replace("R","/").replace("§","R").replace("S","Σ").replace("R",chr(ord("R")+1)).replace("/","R")
    RM=RM.replace("S","Õ").replace("Σ","S").replace("T","σ").replace("S",chr(ord("S")+1)).replace("Õ","S")
    RM=RM.replace("T","Ô").replace("σ","T").replace("U","~").replace("T",chr(ord("T")+1)).replace("Ô","T")
    RM=RM.replace("U","ü").replace("~","U").replace("V","é").replace("U",chr(ord("U")+1)).replace("ü","U")
    RM=RM.replace("V","â").replace("é","V").replace("W","ä").replace("V",chr(ord("V")+1)).replace("â","V")
    RM=RM.replace("W","ç").replace("ä","W").replace("X","ê").replace("W",chr(ord("W")+1)).replace("ç","W")
    RM=RM.replace("X","┐").replace("ê","X").replace("Y","└").replace("X",chr(ord("X")+1)).replace("┐","X")
    RM=RM.replace("Y","─").replace("└","Y").replace("Z","┼").replace("Y",chr(ord("Y")+1)).replace("─","Y")
    RM=RM.replace("Z","╛").replace("┼","Z").replace("A","…").replace("Z",chr(ord("Z")-25)).replace("╛","Z")
elif SFA == "no":
    print("no way")
else:
    print("what?")
    first()
first()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of function scopes. Any variable you declare inside a function is only accessible from inside the function. So, something like you have will not work:

```
def first():
    SFA = input("...")

print(SFA) # error, as SFA is only defined inside the `first` function
```

Possible solutions:

#### 1 - Use a return statement

One solution is to return the `SFA` variable so that it becomes accessible from the main program:

```
def first():
    SFA = input("...")
    return SFA

#main program, now calling first() will return the value of SFA
#and we can use that in the main program
my_SFA = first()
```

#### 2 - Make `SFA` a global variable

Another option is to have SFA be a global variable in the first place, so that it is accessible everywhere in your script.

```
SFA = None

def first():
    global SFA #tell the program you want to use the global SFA, not a local variable
    SFA = input("...")

first() #actually call first() to update SFA's value
#now SFA has the correct value
```